# How to open directory using c code and download data into it

Tags: c, linux, directory, wget

How can I open a directory that is present in the present working directory and download the images with wget into this directory.
The problem is that I can successfully download the images but they get downloaded in the present working directory. How can I change directory in Linux using c code?
Also, after downloading, I have to come back to the current directory.

Comment: Consider using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to download (instead of forking a `wget`)

Answer (score 0):

`chdir` is the call you are looking for.  It changes the working directory.  You can change to the directory you want, download the files then change back to the current directory http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir

Comment: Seems `chdir` has no memory. Can you elaborate on changing it back?